# How to run OpenCV and Arduino PySerial simultaneously

Tags: python, opencv, arduino

I am trying to use Arduino Uno to take a snapshot photo with a webcam. I am using python OpenCV to interface with the camera to capture the video. I also am using pyserial for the Arduino interface so that when a pushbutton is pressed, the Arduino and python will interact and the camera will take the photo. The problem that I am experiencing is that when I am running my serial connection for Arduino, the webcam window does not load a video, e.i. (Not Responding). When I comment out the lines of code pertaining to the serial interface, the camera window frame loads and I am able to view the video. I'm thinking that since both are devices are connected to my computer via USB, PySerial is taking over the serial interface and not allowing the camera video feed to load its data onto the interface for me to view. My question is there a way to interface the two together so that when the Arduino receives a digital input, it will send a "command" to python to make the webcam take a photo? Any suggestion will greatly be appreciated.

Platform:

Windows 10
Python 3.8

Python Code:

```
 import cv2
 import serial

 cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)
 cv2.namedWindow("Object")
 img_counter = 0

 while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    snap = ser.read()
    ser.reset_input_buffer()
    
    if not ret:
        print("failed to grab frame")
        break
        cv2.imshow("Object", frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k%256 == 27:
        # ESC pressed
        print("Program closing...")
        break
    
    elif str(snap) == '1':
        # Button pressed
        img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))
        img_counter += 1

cam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

P.S. Please forgive if this issue seems basic, I am a bit of a novice to this scope of work. I am creating this school project to interface a neural network and a PLC. I also have a Rasberry Pi that I can possibly use to run the Neural Network but that is another area with a learning curve for me lol.

Comment: I can't work out what is connected to what, or how! You have a Windows PC, OpenCV running somewhere and an Arduino attached to something, something else is serial and there's a button and a webcam attached to something. Maybe a diagram would help.

Comment: The webcam is connected to a Windows PC. OpenCV is running in the Anaconda Spyder IDE within the same Windows PC that is connected to the webcam. The Arduino Uno is connected to the same Windows PC that the webcam is connected to. The pushbutton is on a breadboard and is connected to pin 10 on said Arduino device. Both devices (webcam and Arduino are connected to the same computer via USB ports) that is running the OpenCV Python code.

Comment: What's the serial connection doing then please?

Comment: So you aren't really using an Arduino to take a photo like your first sentence says because the PC is the one talking to the camera. And the photo you are taking isn't really a photo, because it's a video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter it the serial connection timeout.

```
ser=serial.Serial(port='comX',baudrate=9600,timeout=.1) #timeout - float type
```

I think no use read(), rather readline(). This data (if intiger) can you convert.

```
#write this in while 
try:
    dat=ser.readline()
    try:
        datInt=int(dat)
    except:
        print('Convert fail')#often readed b'', and may not converted
except:
    print('Serial connecting fail')
```

This datInt value is the writed intiger.
If not intiger, can you string method, and convert with more command.

If you will list or more data read, write here a message.

Good luck!

(sory my english is not perfect)